# I have followed the chartkick installation but the chart only displays 'loading'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

Im looking to integrate some charts in my application, so Im trying to use Chartkick for this. As far as I can tell I followed the setup process from here (https://github.com/ankane/chartkick), which seemed pretty straight forward. But in my views the chart only displays "loading".

I have made sure that I have bundled and I have restarted rails s and also tested it with different models, but reverted to the example from the github page with the User model (in my case I have made 3).

Gemfile:

```
    gem 'chartkick', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
    gem 'groupdate', '~> 4.1'
```

assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
    //= require rails-ujs
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require Chart.bundle
    //= require chartkick
    //= require_tree .
```

Views:

```
    <%= line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

Rails s shows the group_by_date part

```
(0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, (DATE_TRUNC('day', ("searches"."created_at"::timestamptz) AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC')) AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC' AS date_trunc_day_searches_created_at_timestamptz_at_time_zone_etc FROM "searches" WHERE ("searches"."created_at" IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('day', ("searches"."created_at"::timestamptz) AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC')) AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC'
```

Im unsure if I am missing something really obvious or something is interfering or so, but my chart only shows 'Loading...' whenever I pull up the page. Anyone have an idea what the missing part is?

Comment: could share web browser console output? on chrome use `More tools -> developer tools -> console` and is there any red line? as it looks everything is correct, also ensure when you `bundle install` you get all gem installed correctly.

Comment: `(index):82 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined
    at (index):82`
and 
   `new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-1", [["2019-02-06",1],["2019-02-07",0],["2019-02-08",1]], {});`

i bundle installed multiple times :(

Answer (score 3):

For rails 6 using webpacker, putting both:

```
    //= require chartkick
    //= require Chart.bundle
```

and

```
    require("chartkick")
    require("chart.js")
```

in their respective places in application.js worked for me.

The 'Quick Start' here - https://chartkick.com/, tells you to use the first one for rails 5 and sprockets, and the second one for rails 6 and webpacker, which is quite confusing or maybe I just misunderstood the phrasing.

Comment: Also you need to run the command
```yarn add chartkick chart.js```

Answer (score 1):

put it into your view file or head

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

fo slim:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

slim example:

```
- content_for :html_head do
  = javascript_include_tag 'application'
- content_for :title, 'Dashboard'
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying you that it could not find charts javascript. That script is not loaded.

I put following configuration and it is working correctly.

```
gem 'chartkick', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
gem 'groupdate', '~> 4.1'
```

in my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and in my view

```
<%= line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

And it is working, so let us investigate what issue can be. Please run following command on your project root to check gems

```
gem list Chartkick
```

It should give you the following response

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chartkick (3.0.2)
```

It means you have properly installed your gem, otherwise, remove `gem 'chartkick', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'` and change it to `gem 'chartkick'` now runt following command

```
bundle install
```

Another thing I am noticing you have different jquery what is your jquery gem? if you are using `gem 'jquery-rails'` than it should be `//= require jquery3 but you have mentioned it jquery only. I think you better share your Gemfile too.

If you are still facing the issue, I will recommend make a test project and put above configuration as I did and see if it works or not. Also, you can check the content of application.js file in the browser and see if your jquery is loaded and this plugin content loaded or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed your advice and the problem still persists.
```gem list Chartkick``` does return: ```*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chartkick (3.0.2)```

I removed the version specification of the chartkick gem as well ```gem 'chartkick'``` is now what i have in my gemfile.

I will try making a test-app asap, will get back to you after I have done so

Comment: What version of Ruby on Rails you are using? and what about jquery, you can just play with sequence, move bootstrap after chart, location does count in javascript.

Comment: ```rails -v
Rails 5.1.6
```

So i tried it in another app and it works fine. I tried to recreate the application.js to match that of my testing app (sequencing) and it still didnt work ... Ill have a couple more go's unless you have an idea?

Comment: Ok, so in my application.html.erb i have:
`<%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>

    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>`

and when I move the javascript tags above the yield it works

so might need to use `yield :after_js`?

but its still weird that it would work like that in one app but not in the other?

Comment: You need to change sequence do this change `<%= render 'shared/navbar' %> <%= render 'shared/flashes' %> <%= yield %> <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %><%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %><%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>` in javascript you need to bring applications befre all other javascripts.

Comment: Somehow that doesnt work, has to be above the yield for me.
At least in the app im trying to make

Answer (score 0):

I found that chartckick and Chart.bundle must be required before turbolinks.
As in many other cases, turbolinks caching can throw off things

```
//= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
```